# IBM Watson Service for identifying particular characteristic such as "helpfulness" in person's tweets or facebook posts?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, watson-discovery, personality-insights

I am currently exploring three services for identifying person's tweets or facebook post's are **helpfulness** or not:

- Personality Insights
- Natural Language Understanding
- Discovery

will I need to write my on wrapper on these services to identify the **helpfulness** characteristic or is there any other way to just query & get result.

can anyone please guide which service I need to use for this task

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you define helpfulness. Whether it is in general, or helpful to answering a question etc.

For Personality Insights, have a look at https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/personality-insights/models.html which has all the traits, as well as what they mean. The closest trait to helpfulness is probably Conscientiousness.

Neil

Answer (score 2):

According to Neil, sure, all depends on how you define helpfulness.

**Discovery:**

If you want use [Discovery](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/index.html) you need some base to get the data, you can filter the data about you want with `filter`. By using data analysis combined with cognitive intuition to take your unstructured data and enrich it so you can discover the information you *need*.

[image]

**Personality:**

If you want use [Personality](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/personality-insights/index.html), understand personality characteristics, needs, and values in written text. The service uses linguistic analytics to infer individuals' intrinsic personality `characteristics`, including Big Five, Needs, and Values, from digital communications such as email, text messages, *tweets*, and forum posts.

**Watson Knowledge Studio:**

If you want to work with `models` for tweets, you can use [WKS](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/wks/index.html) (Watson knowledge Studio), this service provides easy-to-use tools for annotating unstructured domain literature and uses those annotations to create a custom machine-learning model that understands the language of the domain. The accuracy of the model improves through iterative testing, ultimately resulting in an algorithm that can *learn* from the *patterns* that it sees and *recognize* those patterns in large collections of new documents. For example, if you want learn about car, you can simple give some models to WKS.

[image]